Invariant Violation: requireNativeComponent: "RNJWPlayerView" was not found in the UIManager
I am experiencing a package linking issue only on iOS. The invariant violation error occurs when attempting to stream a video that utilizes the below package.
@jwplayer/jwplayer-react-native": "^1.0.3"

When running 'pod install' with CocoaPods the likely problematic pods are:
'JWPlayerKit'
'RNJWPlayer'

My minimum iOS version is 14.
Relevant Code:
return (
    <Background>
      <View style={styles.videoContainer}>
        <JWPlayer
          style={styles.player}
          config={config}
          ref={(p) => (jwplayer.current = p)}
          onPlay={async () => {}}
          onPause={async () => {saveProgress()}}
          onComplete={async () => {saveProgress()}}
          onFullScreen={PresentFullScreen}
          onFullScreenExit={DismissFullScreen}
          onTime={(event) => {
            const { position, duration } = event.nativeEvent;
            setVideoPosition(position);
          }}
          onPlaybackRateChanged={(event) => {}}
          onAudioTracks={(event) => {}}
          onLockScreenMetadata={(event) => {updateLockScreenMetadata(event)}}
        />
      </View>
    </Background>
  );
}

Things I have already attempted:

Creating a test environment with only the necessary packages to stream videos using '@jwplayer/jwplayer-react-native'.
Deleting my Pods folder and Podfile.lock and reinstalling.
Specifying lower versions of 'JWPlayerKit' in my Podfile to be installed. Particularly version 4.19.2 and 4.21.0

Thank you for any help!

Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Instead [edit] your question and add your code as a [mcve]. What happens when you run your code and what did you expect to happen instead? Any errors? Be more specific,  in the title as well as in the question body. Neither "issue with" nor "not working" are helpful problem descriptions.
